# Google Cloud: Use backup VPC route automatically

Tags: routes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-networking

I'm using the example shown in the official Google Cloud Routes Documentation page ([See this page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpc/routes#individualroutes) under "Priority"), as it closely relates to what I'm trying to achieve.

Lets say I have two routes defined as shown below:

```
NAME                       NETWORK     DEST_RANGE         NEXT_HOP                           PRIORITY 
vpnroute                   default     192.168.0.0/16     [ZONE]/instances/vpninstance          1000 
vpnroute-backup            default     192.168.0.0/16     [ZONE]/instances/vpninstance-backup   2000
```

In the official docs it states:

> Under this configuration, VPN traffic would normally be handled by
>   vpninstance, but would fall back to vpninstance-backup if vpnroute is
>   deleted.

I would like this failover to be automatic. How do I achieve that?

Or in other words : I would like to have Highly Available instances that I'd can use as a nextHop in a routing rule and I'm fine with an Active/Passive model. Whats the easiest way I can achieve this? I like the above solution but it turns out I'd have to manually delete a route when I detect that my primary route's NEXT_HOP is down

My assumption was I could have two routes with differing priorities and the routes would be attempted in the order of priorities if a higher priority route did not work, but I think I might be wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by main and backup VPN tunnels by setting s different priorities to the routes of the two tunnels.
Or you can set routes with the same priority to the two tunnels, then when the two tunnels established the traffic will ECMP between the tunnels.

In both cases when one tunnel become non-established, the route to it will get lower priority, so all the traffic will go through the established tunnel.